# Checkboxes with order - UI/UX and technical issues

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

**Introduction**

An HTML form contains a checkboxes element listing various indicators. The user may choose exactly three items from that list (see image 1). Upon submitting the form, a bubble chart is created, with one indicator each on the x and y axis and the third indicator defining the size of the bubble (see image 2).

**Image 1**

[image: Standard checkboxes]

**Image 2**

[image: Bubble chart]

**Problem**

By choosing the indicators, the user is not able to define the order of the selected indicators. Thus, the user is not able to define, which indicator is on which axis or which indicator is responsible for the bubble size respectively.

**Available solutions**

Of course, instead on having a single multi-select checkboxes field in the web form, (1) one could create three single-select radio elements named **x**, **y**, and **z**. Or, if the form is ajax-powered, (2) additional form elements could be shown to let the user choose the respective options.

However, with option (1), the indicators would be repeated thrice in the form and with option (2) the additional form elements would not be inside the list of indicators. Further, I would like to keep the indicators in one element due to the fact that there are other chart options using a very similar form (they are all generated from the same toolbox) and the processing functions are relying on specific element names (not types though).

**Questions**

I've read about multi-state checkboxes, however, the (only) additional state (indeterminate) is just a visual representation, the checkbox must technically still be either checked or unchecked.

**Q1: Is there another (similar) form element which could be used?**

From what I read, I would assume, that such an element doesn't exist since what I am practically trying to do, is to send two values (indicator id and chart representation).

**Q2: Could someone point me to UI/UX best practices for similar cases?**

Due to the lack of correct (search) terms, I haven't quite found good examples of solving this or similar situations. "multi-state checkboxes" bring up the before-mentioned indeterminate state, "ordered checkboxes" mostly refer to some MS Excel problems.

Comment: maybe something like this? each line has an x,y,z (or whatever they're called) options: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/j794k3me/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if I want to have the Biomass for x and z?
UX is a very difficult topic, and denying choices from a user doesn't make them happy at all.

So my solution, not to the technical question, but the UX one, would be to convert all check boxes to radio items and add an additional selection (either as a dropdown or again as radio items) with which you select either x,y or z.
This can easily be achieved via js and solve the problem at hand easily. Another advantage is that you only use controls with which users are already familiar with, which might be an additional plus :)

Comment: Indeed, using the same indicator for more than one dimension isn't possible with the current setup. And I was thinking about creating three radio buttons for each indicator to allow that. I guess, I am just reluctant to implement that due to the number of changes it would introduce into the whole tool (regarding both validation and submission functions). I was (and still am) hoping, that there is some magic element I haven't heard of, yet. ;)